# Getting the result of a trailing pivot table

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

Basically, I have three tables which are `users`, `position`, `user_position` and I want to get all users with their respective `positions`
**Note that a single user can have multiple positions**

```
    The `user_position` table consists of: 
    - user_id
    - position_id
```

To illustrate... it goes something like this:

> `users`-->`user_position`<--`position`

What I got so far is this:

**User Model**

```
public function user_positions() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\UserPosition', 'user_id', 'id');
}
```

**UserPosition Model**

```
public function positions() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Position', 'position_id', 'id');
}
```

**UserController**

```
public function getallusers() {
    $data = User::with('user_positions')->get();
    return response()->json($data);
}
```

So far it gives me the correct result set.
For example:

```
[{id:1,
  name:'John',
  user_positions:
    [{id:1, 
      user_id:1, 
      position_id: 5
     },
     {id:2, 
      user_id:1, 
      position_id: 9
     }
    ]
 }]
```

However, it is incomplete, I also wanted the `positions` array inside the `user_positions` array but I don't know or I got lost on how to associate/merge/attach (i dont know the right term) the `positions` function to my `User` Model.

Comment: you have to use `belongsToMany`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is a [`BelongsToMany`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) relation.

You could add the following relation to your `User` model.

```php
public function positions()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Position::class);
}
```

You could eager load them with:

```php
User::with('positions')->get();
```

Result:

```json
[{
    ...
    "positions": [{ ...The data of the position... }]
}]
```

Comment: What if I have a non-standard table naming convention. for example, instead of user_position, i got tbl_positions_assigned

Comment: @stackved12 Take alook at the documentation. This is the signature of the method `belongsToMany($related, $table = null, $foreignPivotKey = null, $relatedPivotKey = null, $parentKey = null, $relatedKey = null, $relation = null`. In your case it would be `Position::class, 'tbl_positions_assigned'`.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to `m:m` relation, it's advised to use BelongsToMany, there is no need for an intermediate model for the "pivoted" table.

If you have non-eloquent standard naming conventions. Then you have to specify the table name in the 2nd parameter as followed:

```
return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Positions', 'tbl_positions_assigned');
```

In the 3rd and 4th parameter you specify the foreign key names.

I'd like to refer to you to the documentation [Eloquent-relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) as it's very thoroughly explained over there.

One very strong thing you can do with `belongsToMany` is to append extra columns in the pivot table. Those are also easily obtained from the pivot table. This is useful if you wish to store extra data values specific to the model.

```
return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Positions')->wherePivot('active', 1);
```

With above example you could exclude certain values, that are not `active` in this example, when you retrieve the results from the query.